# Missing property in AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition ContainerDefinition

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

I have been building a ECS stack in CDK with Go and have hit an annoying roadblock. I need to access the StopTimeout property, however, this seems to be missing from the Go TaskDefinition.AddContainer Method params. It's weird because it's there in Python CDK. I'm not sure why it should be missing from the Go CDK.

Is there a non painful way to tack on a property? I dont really want to shift to using the CfnTaskDefinition because it would be a pain to implement that in the stack I already have.

```
        taskDefinition.AddContainer(jsii.String(deploymentEnv+service.Tag+"ContainerDef"), &awsecs.ContainerDefinitionOptions{
            Essential: jsii.Bool(true),
            Image:     awsecs.AssetImage_FromEcrRepository(ecrRepository, aws.String("latest")),
            ContainerName:        jsii.String(service.Name + "-" + deploymentEnv), 
            MemoryReservationMiB: &service.MemoryReservation,
            PortMappings: &[]*awsecs.PortMapping{
                &awsecs.PortMapping{ContainerPort: &service.ContainerPort}, 
            },
            Logging: awsecs.AwsLogDriver_AwsLogs(&awsecs.AwsLogDriverProps{
                StreamPrefix: aws.String("ecs"+service.Name),
                LogGroup:     cwLogGroup,
            }),
            //I need to set StopTimeout :(
        })
```

It seems as though this could be done through escape hatches however - there is no Cfn object for ContainerDefinition directly. There is only a struct for TaskDefinitionContainerDefinition and i cant seem to use this in an escape hatch.

```
containerDefinition := taskDefinition.AddContainer(jsii.String(deploymentEnv+service.Tag+"ContainerDef"), &awsecs.ContainerDefinitionOptions{
        Essential: jsii.Bool(true),
        Image:     awsecs.AssetImage_FromEcrRepository(ecrRepository, aws.String("latest")),
        ContainerName:        jsii.String(service.Name + "-" + deploymentEnv), 
        MemoryReservationMiB: &service.MemoryReservation,
        PortMappings: &[]*awsecs.PortMapping{
            &awsecs.PortMapping{ContainerPort: &service.ContainerPort}, 
        },
        Logging: awsecs.AwsLogDriver_AwsLogs(&awsecs.AwsLogDriverProps{
            StreamPrefix: aws.String("ecs"+service.Name),
            LogGroup:     cwLogGroup,
        }),
    })
    

    cdChild := containerDefinition.Node().DefaultChild().(awsecs.CfnTaskDefinition_ContainerDefinitionProperty)
    cdChild.StopTimeout = aws.Float64(699)
```

Comment: The `StopTimeout` field is in the `awsecs.ContainerDefinitionOptions` struct from the very beginning. See [v1.95.0-devpreview](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-cdk-go/awscdk@v1.95.0-devpreview/awsecs#ContainerDefinitionOptions) and [v2.0.0-alpha.10](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-cdk-go/awscdk/v2@v2.0.0-alpha.10/awsecs#ContainerDefinitionOptions). Have I missed something?

Comment: It's there: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-cdk-go/awscdk/v2/awsecs#ContainerDefinitionOptions